# Looking for buildout.cfg for old version of Plone (pre-3.2)

Tags: plone, buildout, plone-3.x

Is there a repeatable way of generating older sample Plone buildouts?

Specifically I'm looking for buildout format that's been used for the releases before Plone 3.2, as it was the first release that shipped with buildout by default. I know there are buildouts out there for Plone 3.x but googling for the didn't help me.

I'm trying to convert a Plone 3.0.4 project instance that's been set up with unified installer into buildout. I would like to get a repeatable, documented installation process, before figuring out what to do with the codebase, and most of the accessible examples are for Plone 4.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic template produced by `paster create -t plone3_buildout` (old ZopeSkel<3.0). I used Plone version 3.1 below, you must adjust it with your version (...or simply: use ZopeSkel as I did).

```
[buildout]
parts =
    plone
    zope2
    productdistros
    instance
    zopepy

versions = versions


# Add additional egg download sources here. dist.plone.org contains archives
# of Plone packages.
find-links =
    http://dist.plone.org
    http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty

# Add additional eggs here
# elementtree is required by Plone
eggs =
    elementtree

# Reference any eggs you are developing here, one per line
# e.g.: develop = src/my.package
develop =

[versions]
# Version pins for new style products go here
plone.recipe.zope2instance = 3.6

[plone]
# For more information on this step and configuration options see:
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.plone
recipe = plone.recipe.plone==3.1


[zope2]
# For more information on this step and configuration options see:
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2install
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2install
fake-zope-eggs = true
url = ${plone:zope2-url}

# Use this section to download additional old-style products.
# List any number of URLs for product tarballs under URLs (separate
# with whitespace, or break over several lines, with subsequent lines
# indented). If any archives contain several products inside a top-level
# directory, list the archive file name (i.e. the last part of the URL,
# normally with a .tar.gz suffix or similar) under 'nested-packages'.
# If any archives extract to a product directory with a version suffix, list
# the archive name under 'version-suffix-packages'.
[productdistros]
# For more information on this step and configuration options see:
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.distros
recipe = plone.recipe.distros
urls =
nested-packages =
version-suffix-packages =

[instance]
# For more information on this step and configuration options see:
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
zope2-location = ${zope2:location}
user = admin:admin
http-address = 8080
#debug-mode = on
#verbose-security = on
# If you want Zope to know about any additional eggs, list them here.
# This should include any development eggs you listed in develop-eggs above,
# e.g. eggs = Plone my.package
eggs =
    ${buildout:eggs}
    ${plone:eggs}

# If you want to register ZCML slugs for any packages, list them here.
# e.g. zcml = my.package my.other.package
zcml =

products =
    ${buildout:directory}/products
    ${productdistros:location}
    ${plone:products}

[zopepy]
# For more information on this step and configuration options see:
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.egg
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${instance:eggs}
interpreter = zopepy
extra-paths = ${zope2:location}/lib/python
scripts = zopepy
```

The core is the `plone.recipe.plone` recipe, used for old Plone.

Comment: Installing ZopeSkel==2.21.2 in Python 2.4 virtualenv then running plone3_buildout template generates exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Do you do anything special in order to pin setuptools to the version that supports Python 2.4? whenever I run buldout generated with plone3_buildout it tries to go and fetch setuptools==14.3.1

Comment: Never mind, pinning correct version of setuptoos under [versions] seems to work.

Comment: @AlexVolkov so which version you used? Reporting this here will make this QA more useful for future reference

Comment: I used version 1.4.2, like this -- https://gist.github.com/avolkov/1e13944949c1b802bfd7 I also had to run a custom bootstrap command -- $  python bootstrap.py --distribute -c buildout.cfg, description is here -- https://github.com/thet/buildout-base/blob/master/README.rst. I used Plock Pins as buildout config examples that @aclark posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Plock Pins](http://plock.github.io):

- https://github.com/plock/pins/blob/master/plone-3-1
- https://github.com/plock/pins/blob/master/plone-3-0
- https://github.com/plock/pins/blob/master/plone-2-5
- https://github.com/plock/pins/blob/master/plone-2-1
- https://github.com/plock/pins/blob/master/plone-2-0
- https://github.com/plock/pins/blob/master/plone-1-1

E.g.:

```
[buildout]
extends = https://github.com/plock/pins/blob/master/plone-3-1
```

Comment: I tried using that for plone-3-0, but at this time it seems to be pulling Plone 5 and related eggs, such as Zope2, there is no Plone egg for pre-3.2 releases, I think there's a version pin is missing somewhere. https://gist.github.com/avolkov/674c9663374b79128297